# multiplying polynomials in GF(2)

Tags: c#, math

i want to multiply 2 polynomials in gf(2) in c#. please help.

Comment: You need to provide more information regarding the problems you have with this. Is it the maths? Is it conversion to code? Is your code throwing up an error?

Answer (score 4):

You would probably want to use bitwise operators, and represent the polynomials using the `ulong` or `uint` type.  That is, if P<sub>64</sub>(GF(2)) is acceptable.  If not, you will have to use some other trick.

```
ulong a, b;
// Compute r = x * y
ulong r = 0;
for (uint i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    if ((a & (1 << i)) != 0) {
        r ^= b << i;
    }
}
```

A summary of the representation:

- `z & (1 << i)` selects the x<sup>i</sup> coefficient from z(x)
- `r ^= b << i` computes r'(x) = r(x) + b(x)*x<sup>i</sup>

Disclaimer: I am not a C# programmer.

Answer (score 2):

OK.

- define a class which represents a Galois Field.
- define a class which represents a polynomial over a field.
- define a multiplication operator on polynomials
- and you're done.

Perhaps you can be more explicit about the step where you're having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a big question, which mostly depends on the type of the fields you have to use.

A good introduction is Sage's [manual page](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/rings/finite_field.html) for finite fields computation.

Executive Summary: For small fields (|F|<2<sup>16</sup>) use tables of Zech logs via the Givaro C++ library. For bigger fields use `PARI`. Fields of characteristic 2 (which is what you need) use `NTL`.

A paper about implementation of fields is [available at ACM](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1428156), it describes how was it done with Maxima Computer Algebra System.

But if you just need a small toy library to factor polynomials over fields for homework assignment here's what I would do:

1. Create a class which represents a polynomial, it should adds multiply and divides polynomials. A polynomial is easily representable as an array. Make the polynomial class a generic class, like so `Polynomial<coefficient_type>`.
2. Create a class which represents the group Z<sub>p</sub>, for prime `p`. This class will be the coefficients of the polynomial. Use Z<sub>2</sub> for your fields.
3. Create a class that factors a polynomial.
4. To represent GF(p<sup>k</sup>) find an irreducible polynomial of degree k, and all polynomials of degree up to k over Z<sub>p</sub> are your elements.
5. Adding them is easy (add coefficients, they are already in Z<sub>p</sub>)
6. After multiplying two polynomials, make sure you divide the result modulo the irreducible polynomial chosen in `4`.

Thus you'll achieve a generic simple program which can add and multiply elements over all finite fields!